# Why is data-bind: enable only working in some cases?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im trying to enable some buttons when  $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted is true. This only works in some cases. For my buttons in the end of the file the expression is always false, even though its set to true when I inspect the property.

```
<div id="headerContent" style="display: none" data-bind="visible: menu.isMenuActive('Questions')">
    <fieldset data-bind="with: questions">
        <legend>Questions <span data-bind="text: headerName"></span></legend>
        <div class="alert alert-info" data-bind="visible: $parent.blockId == 0">
            You must save before you can add questions
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: $parent.blockId > 0">
            <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="click: addQuestion, enable:writeEnabled">Add Question</button>
            <div class="control-group">

                <div data-bind="sortable: {data:groups, beforeMove:$root.questions.allowGroupDrop, afterMove : $root.questions.saveGroupOrder}" class="pointer">
                    <div>
                        <h1><i class="icon-move topMargin10"></i>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text:number() + '. ' + name()"></span></h1>
                        <div data-bind="if:questions">
                            <table >
                            <tbody data-bind="sortable: {data:questions,  afterMove : $root.questions.saveOrder,  beforeMove: $root.questions.allowQuestionDrop, options : {handle : '.sortableHandle', cursor: 'move'} }">
                            <tr class="items">
                            <td class="sortableHandle moveCursor"  width="770px" >
                            <!-- <label data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></label> -->
                            <i class="icon-move"></i>&nbsp;
                            <span data-bind="style: { textDecoration:disabled() ? 'line-through' : 'normal' }, click:$root.questions.editQuestion, text: $parentContext.$index()+1 + '.' + (order()+1) + '. ' + shortText()"></span>

                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini right" style="float:right; width:48px; text-align: center;"
                            data-bind="visible:$data.canBeDeleted() && $root.questions.writeEnabled, click: $root.questions.deleteQuestion">Delete</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-mini right" style="float:right; width:48px; text-align: center;"
                            data-bind="visible:$data.canBeDisabled() && $root.questions.writeEnabled, click: $root.questions.disableQuestion">Disable</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-mini right" style="float:right; width:48px; text-align: center;"
                            data-bind="visible:$data.canBePublished() && $root.questions.writeEnabled, click: $root.questions.publishQuestion">Publish </button>

                            <!-- ko foreach:options-->
                            <div class="left" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:2px" data-bind="if:subQuestion.text">
                            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: subQuestion.text()"></span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /ko-->
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="hidden" data-bind="jqdialog : {title : $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() || !$root.questions.writeEnabled()  ? 'View Question' : 'Edit Question', trigger: questions.editQuestionDialog.isOpen, options: {width:880, position: ['center',180]}}">
    <div class="control-group" data-bind="if: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question">
    <form style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <div data-bind="if: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question">
    <div class="control-group" data-bind="with:questions, visible: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption == null ">
    <div class="controls-row">
    <label class="span10 wellLabel">Question Group</label>
    </div>

    <div class="controls controls-row">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select data-bind="visible: (!editQuestionDialog.addGroupIsActive() && !editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled()) , value : editQuestionDialog.question().questionGroupId,
    options: groups,
    optionsText: 'name',
    optionsValue : 'id'"></select>
    <input type="text" data-bind="visible:editQuestionDialog.addGroupIsActive() && !editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled(), textInput:editQuestionDialog.newGroupName, hasFocus:editQuestionDialog.addGroupHasFocus, event: { keyup: editQuestionDialog.inputnewGroupkeyUp }" />
    <input type="text" disabled data-bind="visible:!editQuestionDialog.addGroupIsActive() && editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled(), value:editQuestionDialog.groupName()" />
    </td>
    <td>
    <label class="btn btn-info" data-bind="visible: !editQuestionDialog.addGroupIsActive() && !editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() , click:editQuestionDialog.addGroup" type="button">Add new group</label>

    <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="visible:editQuestionDialog.addGroupIsActive , click:editQuestionDialog.saveGroup">Save Group</label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="visible:editQuestionDialog.viewCancel, click:editQuestionDialog.closeAddGroup">Cancel</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible:questions.editQuestionDialog.question().questionGroupId">
    <div data-bind="if:questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption">
    <div class="well">
    <span class="label label-info">Sub question</span>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: questions.editQuestionDialog.openParentQuestion, text:questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption.question.order()+1 + '. ' + questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption.question.text() "></a></li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li> <span data-bind=" text:questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption.text()"></span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label class="span7 wellLabel">Question</label>
    <label class="span3 wellLabel">Required</label>
    </div>

    <div class="controls controls-row">
    <input type="text" id="editQuestiontext" class="input-medium span7" data-bind="textInput: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().text, enable:!$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted" maxlength="300" />
    <select class="span3" data-bind="enable:!$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, options: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.isCorrectOptions, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().isRequired"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label class="span10 wellLabel">Type of question</label>
    </div>

    <div class="controls-row" data-bind="disable:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled()">
    <div id=questionTypeChoice class="btn-group" data-bind="with:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog">
    <button class="btn" type="button" data-bind="click:function(){setQuestionType(2);}, css :{'btn-primary' :question().type() == 2}">Yes/No</button>
    <button class="btn"  type="button" data-bind="click:function(){setQuestionType(1);},css :{'btn-primary' : question().type() == 1}">Free text</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" data-bind="click:function(){setQuestionType(3);},css :{'btn-primary' : question().type() == 3}">Single choice</button>
    <button class="btn" type="button" data-bind="click:function(){setQuestionType(4);},css :{'btn-primary' : question().type() == 4}">Multi choice</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.showOptions">
    <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label class="wellLabel span10">Options</label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr class="primary">
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Is correct</th>
    <th colspan="3">Points</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="visible: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().type() > 2">
    <tr class="success">
    <td class="span4">
    <input type="text" class="span5"  data-bind="enable: !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, textInput:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.newOption.text, hasFocus:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.newOption.hasFocus" />
    </td>
    <td class="span2">
    <select class="span1" data-bind="enable:!$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, options: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.isCorrectOptions, optionsText : 'text', optionsValue:'value', value :$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.newOption.isCorrect "></select>
    </td>
    <td class="span2">
    <select class="span1" data-bind="enable:!$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, options:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.pointValues, value:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.newOption.point"></select>
    </td>

    <td class="span2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="visible: !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled(), click: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.addNewOption, enable:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.newOption.text().length > 0">Add</button>
    </td>


    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <div disabled>

    <tbody id="dataGrid" data-bind="foreach: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.optionsForType">

    <tr  class="sortable-bulk moveCursor", draggable="true" data-bind="disable:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled(), event:{drop: function(data,e) {$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.doOptionDrop(e,data);},
    dragover:function(data,e) {$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.doAllowOptionDrop(e,data);},
    dragleave:function(data,e) {$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.doDragOptionLeave(e,data);},
    dragstart:function(data,e) {return $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.doOptionDrag(e,data);}}">
    <td class="span4" >
    <div>
    <div>
    <input  id="optText" onclick="this.focus(); this.blur(); this.focus();" type="text" class="span5" data-bind="enable: !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, textInput:text"/></td>
    </div>
    </div>
    <td class="span2">
    <select class="span1" data-bind="enable: !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, options: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.isCorrectOptions, optionsText : 'text', optionsValue:'value', value :isCorrect, event : {change : $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.isCorrectHasChanged}"></select>
    </td>
    <td class="span2">
    <select class="span1" data-bind="enable: !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted, options:$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.pointValues, value:point"></select>
    </td>
    <td class="span4">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.removeOption, visible: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().type() > 2 && !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled()">Remove</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="visible : $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption == null && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().type() != 4 && !$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled(), click: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.addSubQuestion, text: subQuestion.text() != null ? 'Edit sub question' : 'Create sub' ">Sub question</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-bind="visible : $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().parentOption == null && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().type() != 4 && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsDisabled() && subQuestion.text() != null , click: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.addSubQuestion, text: subQuestion.text() != null ? 'Show sub question' : null ">Sub question</button>

    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </div>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </form>
    </div>
<div>
    <button style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px" class="btn pull-right" data-bind="click: questions.editQuestionDialog.close">Close</button>
    <button style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" data-bind="click: questions.editQuestionDialog.clearQuestion, enable: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted">Clear</button>
    <button style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-bind="click: questions.editQuestionDialog.saveQuestion, enable:questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsValid && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted">Save</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

The code is all the code in the same file and the expression works in all other places but for the "Save" and "Clear" buttons at the bottom of the file. What could be the problem? Do you need to write the expression differently for data-bind: visible and enable?

Comment: What is the value of `$root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted`? Is it a plain JS value or an observable/computed? Because if it's not an observable KO will not know when to re-evaluate it.

Comment: I think it is an observable KO. I found this in the code as well.     self.getNewQuestion = function() {
        var q = ko.mapping.fromJS(json.emptyQuestion);
        q.isRequired = ko.observable(true);
        q.canBeDisabled=ko.observable(false);
        q.canBeDeleted=ko.observable(true);
        q.canBePublished=ko.observable(true);
        return q;
    };

Comment: OK, so `enable: $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted` *should* work as far as I remember KO (haven't worked with it in a while). It will bind directly to the observable. `questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsValid && $root.questions.editQuestionDialog.question().canBeDeleted` is a different matter - since it's not a single property, KO should evaluate that expression differently. But I wouldn't expect this to be always `false`

Comment: Is `questions.editQuestionDialog.questionIsValid` correct? It doesn't have `$root` in the beginning like the other value

Comment: It doesent seem to matter if I use $root in the beginning or not.

Comment: Hmm, I'm out of ideas here. What I'll suggest is to use the [KO context debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en) - last time I used it, it was pretty useful. It also only works in Chrome (unless there was a different addon made since I've used it). You can use it to check what the context *actually* says. Right now I suspect the KO binding failed - that is a pretty common reason for what you saw. It's usually due to some sort of error - syntax or something. I can't see any here but I dunno.

Comment: Any binding errors in the console?

Comment: Your HTML looks a little strange. Divs within tables, unclosed elements etc. I wonder if knockout isn't getting confused about what the current context is. I would go through and match up your opening and closing tags and make sure everything is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by just moving my buttons inside of the form a few rows up. Not really sure why this works but I'm guessing it has to do with the bindings as someone said.